# How to call treeView.SelectedItemChanged programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, selecteditemchanged

In my program I would like to call to a `SelectedItemChanged` event using c# code-behind, I am just unsure about what to pass as parameters. This is for a `TreeViewItem`.

```
//Gets selected item in TreeView
private void TreeOne_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    MainWindowViewModel.SelectedItem = e.NewValue as TreeViewItem;
}

//I'm calling the SelectedItemChanged event from a RightButtonDown event
private void TreeOne_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    TreeOne_SelectedItemChanged(/* What would go here? **/);
}
```

Also, when I try to build this I receive this compiler error that pretty much led to this question...

> No overload for method `TreeOne_SelectedItemChanged` takes '0' arguments

I'm hoping that this is an easy question, but if I have not provided enough information, or haven't been clear enough please let me know.

Comment: Can you show more code?

Comment: Sure, check my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to @Bart Friederichs' answer and assuming that you have a reference to your `TreeView`, you could add the following method:

```
private void SetSelectedItem()
{
     MainWindowViewModel.SelectedItem = TreeOne.SelectedItem;
}
```

Then you can simply call this from wherever you like:

```
private void TreeOne_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    SetSelectedItem();
}

private void TreeOne_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    SetSelectedItem();
}
```

Comment: This works well too, thanks. I changed my answer to this one because I am using this now.

Answer (score 0):

The usual design pattern would be to call some kind of processing method, and not to "manually" fire events:

```
private TreeOne_SelectedItemChaned(object sender, 
                        RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e) {
    processChange();
}
```

Then, from withing your code, you just call `processChange()`, no need to call `TreeOne_SelectedItemChanged`.

Comment: So where does `processChange()` actually go? If you look at my code you'll see that I have operations being performed under `SelectedItemChanged`. I still want those to happen.

Comment: In your case it is interesting. Where would you get `e.NewValue` from when calling from `TreeOne_MouseRightButtonDown` ?

Comment: Well originally I just tried using `MainWindowViewModel.SelectedItem = e.NewValue as TreeViewItem` in my `TreeOne_MouseRightButtonDown` event, but I received a compiler error having to do with `NewValue`. That's why I am trying to call `SelectedItemChanged` instead.

Answer (score 0):

try to call

TreeOne_SelectedItemChanged(null, null);

Comment: This will result in a `NullPointerException` on `e.NewValue`.

Comment: It does, but I just said `if(e == null) return;` and `if(sender == null) return;`