# Select a TreeViewItem on Right-Click

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, selecteditem, right-click

I would like to be able to select a `TreeViewItem` in my program on right-click. Previously, (In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335723/how-to-call-selecteditemchanged-programmatically)) I tried to do this by calling to `SetSelectedItem()` method from wherever I wanted to allow a `TreeViewItem` to be selected. The answer from that question compiled and ran, but did not actually allow the `TreeViewItem` to become selected like I wanted.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797966/in-wpf-how-do-i-select-the-treeview-item-under-my-cursor-on-right-click) that I've been looking at is pretty much the exact same question as this one, with the exception of the `hierachicalDataTemplate`. My `TreeView` does not have a `hierachicalDataTemplate`, and if it is unnecessary for my program I would like to avoid it.

This is what I have compiling, but not affecting change right now...

```
//Sets selected item in TreeView and passes to MainWindowViewModel
private void SetSelectedItem()
{
       MainWindowViewModel.SelectedItem = Tree_One.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem;
}

//**** This is the function this question is about -- It's Supposed to select item on RightClick
private void Tree_One_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
       SetSelectedItem();    
}
```

So just for clarity, the node that I right click does not get selected like expected. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

**UPDATE:**

I think I know what the problem is after playing around with the answer below. The code I have in this question doesn't actually change the selected item, it just kind of reiterates through the selection of the currently selected item, re-selecting it. If there was a way to actually change the selected item to the item that is right clicked, it would run perfectly. Any clue on how to do something like that?

Comment: In handler of `MouseRightButtonDown` try write this: `TreeViewItem Item = sender as TreeViewItem; if (Item != null) { Item.IsSelected = true; }`

Comment: Tried it with no luck. Odd.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select TreeView Node on right click before displaying ContextMenu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592373/select-treeview-node-on-right-click-before-displaying-contextmenu)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer by @alex2k8 on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592373/select-treeview-node-on-right-click-before-displaying-contextmenu) is exactly what I was looking for, and is what I used to solve my problem.

Thanks to anyone who helped out.

Answer (score 2):

sorry for my bad englisch.
Well I'm working with the MS VS 2017 Version 15.9.1.

So - all your ways for selected a treeviewItem via right mouse click dosn't work - I don't know why.

But I find a working way:

```
private void Treeview1_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e){

    // The source from the Mouse Event Args is a TreeViewItem.
    var treeViewitem = e.Source as TreeViewItem;

    // Than works your Code in the above Posts!
    if (treeViewitem != null)
    {
        treeViewitem.IsSelected = true;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

cu 
Marc

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(e.Source.GetType().Name);` alway show TreeView

Answer (score 0):

Please see the sample snippet below wich is able to get the selected item

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Items = new List<Item>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Items.Add(new Item() {ItemName="Item " + i.ToString() });
        }
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void TreeView1_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((sender as TreeView).SelectedItem != null)
        {
            Item itm = (Item)(sender as TreeView).SelectedItem;
            Console.WriteLine(itm.ItemName);
        }
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
}
```

XAML

```
<TreeView Name="TreeView1" MouseRightButtonDown="TreeView1_MouseRightButtonDown" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: I'm getting an `InvalidCastException` run time error for the `TreeView itm = (TreeView)...` line. And then when I try to fix that by entering in `TreeViewItem` it says that `System...TreeViewItem` does not contain a definition for 'SelectedItem'`... Why is this? I feel like this shouldn't be happening.

Comment: @Eric after dark : Not "TreeViewItem itm", it is "Item itm". You are casting selectedItem to TreviewItem. that is wrong. Please see my code and use the same line

Comment: I am not using a `List` though, I am using an `ObservableCollection<TreeViewItem>`.

Answer (score -1):

This might be a bit outdated but I just found a very nice solution to this. At least imo.

TreeView now supports a NodeMouseClick event in which you can select the clicked node.

```
private void treeView_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        this.treeView.SelectedNode = e.Node;
```

Comment: this is for windows forms